# Calculating a nested manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

In the context of this question I say that:

- a manifold is *convex* $\iff$ no line intersects it in more than two points
- a manifold $B$ is nested (in the sense of [Matryoshka dolls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matryoshka_doll)) inside a *convex* manifold $A$ $\iff$ a line's intersections with $B$ are in the line's open finite interval defined by its intersections with $A$.

> **Question:**
>
> Given a *convex* manifold $A$, how can the *nested* manifold $B$ be calculated
>
> - whose tangent lines intersect $A$ in exactly two points $p$ and $q$ at a positive distance $\|q-p\|\ge c$ and
> - for every point $b\in B$ at least one tangent line exists for which the intersection holds, i.e. for which the distance between the intersection intersection points $p$ and $q$ is exactly $c$
>
> provided $c$ is smaller than the *diameter* of the largest sphere that fits into $A$

I am especially interested in the case where $A$ is an ellipse in the case of the Euclidean plane  resp. of rotational ellipsoids and there in the case where the major axis is the rotational axis in the case of Euclidean space.

Manifold $B$ can also be interpreted as the "inner" hull of the set of line-segments that connect the center of a sphere of radius $c$ that is centered at a point of $A$ with the points in the intersection of such a sphere's boundary with $A$ taking the union over all such spheres.

In the case of an ellipse that amounts to sliding a line-segment of lengtn $c$ whose endpoints are on the ellipse's boundary around the ellipse as depicted below:

[image]

Comment: So $B$ is "nested" means that $B$ is contained in the convex hull of $A$?

Comment: @BenMcKay yes that‘s what I mean, I didn‘t use „contained“ behause it could be confusing when  interpreted set theoretic

Comment: @MattF. I have edited the question following your suggestion; thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Do you know that the nested manifold exists? I tried calculating it for the ellipse $(x/2)^2+(y/3)^2=1$ with $c=1$: the curve would have to satisfy a first-order differential equation with the boundary conditions $y(0)=3\sqrt{3}/2$, $y'(0)=0$, $y(4\sqrt{2}/3)=0$, $y'(4\sqrt{2}/3)=-\infty$, and I did not find anything satisfying all of them.

Comment: @MattF. It can't be guaranteed that the nested manifold exists for every $c$ in the limits I stated; that was merely an educated guess for the upper bound, but reasons of continuity I would expect that such a manifold must exist for sufficiently small positive $c$.